# Are there any issues (not legal) of using a name (from character, creature etc ) from a media franchise?

Tags: fiction

For instance let's say about these two things:

- a story featuring a race called "Tuskarr", a name from Warcraft universe.
- a story featuring a character called "Yogg-Saron" also from Warcraft.

Are there any issues (not copyright/trademark related) of using such names? (Assuming that the characterisctics are changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring potential legal issues, there's a risk in using any pre-existing name: It may affect the readers' expectations and perception about the race or character. If the race/character is very similar to the original, this may work in your favour. However, if they only share the name or are only superficially similar but differ in important detail, it could be confusing or distracting.